# EF : setting a value for foreign key column during Create() forces reload from the foreign entities?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I've a class **Personnel** which has a relation to a **FunctionType**.

```
public partial class Personnel
{
    #region Primitive Properties
    public virtual long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Nullable<long> FunctionType_Id
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual FunctionType FunctionType
    #endregion
}
```

I've the following **FunctionTypes** in the database:

```
id | name
---+-----
5  | five
10 | ten
```

When I create a new **Personnel** entity like this:

```
var p = new Personnel
{
    Name = "abc",
    FunctionType_Id = 5
};
```

and add this entity to the DbSet:

```
dbSet.Add(p);
```

and save it (*context is a DbContext*):

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

the EF gets first all Personnels related to FunctionType = 5 before adding the entity using an INSERT statement in the database ? (For tracing this I used SQL Profiler)

This query can have a negative performance impact in case there a lot of personnels already associated with that FunctionType.

Can someone explain what's wrong in the design ?

Comment: Please provide unambiguous code that makes sense. `FunctionType = 5` will not compile unless there an implicit conversion. Some properties are shown as fields.

Comment: Fixed to "FunctionType_Id = 5"

Comment: Show the segment of code where you save the entity.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems that the problem lies in the generated entities. The entities (Personnel and FunctionType) where generated using a POCO template.

When I switched to **ADO.NET DBContext Generator**, all strange behaviour was solved.

However I do not have a detailed explanation for this, does someone know more about this ?